# Releasing UIImageViews for memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I will constantly call this method multiple times:

```
-(void)entityMaker {
    UIImageView *entity;

    NSUInteger image = [self getRandomNumberBetween:0 to:1];
    NSUInteger xPosition = [self getRandomNumberBetween:20.0 to:self.width - 20.0];

    entity = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPosition, 20, 20, 20)];
    [entity setImage:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:image]];
    [self.view addSubview:entity];

    [self performSelector:@selector(animate:) withObject:entity afterDelay:2.0];
}

-(void)animate:(UIImageView *)image {
    [image release];
    //release has been deprecated 
}
```

But, I don't want millions of image to stay on the screen.

How can I get rid of them (after any set number of seconds) so that they no longer take up memory and or no longer being displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no strong reference to the image view (which you don't in the code you posted), it will be deallocated after you remove it from its superview.

```
-(void)animate:(UIImageView *)image {
    [image removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a property UIImageView and just update the image eveytime instead of creating a new UIImageView every-time and removing it.